# Search Bar displaying results in both sections of Table View

Tags: arrays, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar, sections

I have a problem in my iOS app, I added 2 sections to my table view but, the search bar is displaying its results in both of my sections instead of just once over all.

Just guessing here, but may the problem be because the search bar doesn't have it's own section so it places the results in both? Do I have to add another section? Fix the code? Or add another tableview/ view controller to handle the filteredArray?

**Code:**

`dataArray` is where I have all my arrays from my server

`followedArray` is where certain arrays go from dataArray

`filteredArray` is the searched arrays from dataArray

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
if (!isFiltered) {

    if (section == 0) {
        return [followedArray count];
    }
    else {
        return [dataArray count];
    }
}
return [filteredArray count];
```

**titleForHeaderInSection**

```
if (section == 0) {
    return @"Followed Data";
}
else {
    return @"All Data";
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
Data * dataObject;
if (!isFiltered) {

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        dataObject = [followedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        dataObject = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
else {
    dataObject = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

**searchBar textDidChange**

```
if (searchText.length == 0) {
    isFiltered = NO;
} else {
    isFiltered = YES;

    filteredArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.dataName contains[c] %@", searchText];
    filteredArray = [dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
[myTableView reloadData];
```

**--------------------------------**

What am I doing wrong here? Or am I missing something?

I want to have my followedArray in Section 1, dataArray in Section 2, and the filteredArray when searching the dataArray with the Search Bar to display it independently and not in both sections like how it's doing it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple answer but I was new to iOS

```
// Title for Header
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

        if section == 0 {
            return "Followed Data"
        }
        else {
            return "All Data"
        }
    }

    return "Filtered Data"
}

// Number of Rows in Section
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

        if section == 0 {

            return followedArray.count
        }
        else if (section == 1) {

            return dataArray.count
        }
    }

    return filteredArray.count
}

// Number of Sections
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if !(searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "") {

        return 2
    }

    return 1
}
```